# Laravel imap get messages sorted by most recent

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I am using [laravel-imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap) to retrieve messages from a mailbox:

```
$aMessage = $selectedFolder->query()->setFetchFlags(true)->setFetchBody(true)->setFetchAttachment(false)->leaveUnread()
->limit(40, $highest_page)->get();
```

On default the most recent messages are on the highest page. If I simply get all messages and display them as they are I see the old ones first (page 1).

What I tried so far:

After I call `->get()` the results can be treated as a normal laravel collection, but I had no success with these methods:

```
$aMessage = $aMessage->sortByDesc('date')->values()->all();

$aMessage = $aMessage->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
    //\Log::info(print_r($item, true));
    return $item->date;
})->values()->all();
```

I am sure the methods above do not work because I use `->limit(40, $highest_page)`, which means the collection has a size of 40.

If I dont limit the results and use slice I encounter a timeout error, because there are too many messages in the mailbox:

```
$aMessage = $selectedFolder->query()->setFetchFlags(true)->setFetchBody(true)->setFetchAttachment(false)->leaveUnread()
->get()->reverse()->slice(0, $messages_per_page);
```

I also tried laravel-imap's method `paginate()`. The results were the same as with `limit()`.

At this point I am sure I have to sort somehow before the results turn into a collection. I also found:

```
'options' => [
    'fetch_order' => 'desc',
]
```

The options are added to the Client. I tried asc and desc. I also cleared config cache, but nothing works.

I still see the oldest results on page 1 and the most recent at the end.

Someone has more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with several solutions I decided to go into the vendor file (config/imap.php) and change the fetch_order there:

```
'fetch_order' => 'desc'
```

It was asc on default. It seems that changing the fetch_order when creating the client does not override the config. I had this before and it did not work, also no errors were thrown:

```
$this->oClient = new Client([
    'host'          => env('MAIL_HOST_IN'),
    'port'          => env('MAIL_PORT_IN'),
    'encryption'    => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION_IN'),
    'validate_cert' => true,
    'username'      => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password'      => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'protocol'      => 'imap',
    'options' => [
        'fetch_order' => 'desc',
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**// Get the messages in the inbox**

$messages = $folder->messages()->all();

**// Paginate the messages in descending order and retrieve 5 items per page**

$messages = $messages->setFetchOrder("desc")->paginate(5);

**// Reverse the order of the paginated results without creating a new instance**

$messages->setCollection(collect(array_reverse($messages->items())));

**to imap.php**

'fetch_order' => 'desc',

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).